# RESTful design of convert, calculate

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

How to design operations like:

- calculate
- convert
- translate

For example: convert from "EUR" to "CNY" amount "100".

Is this `/convert?from=EUR&to=CNY&amount=100` RESTful ?

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing in

```
/convert?from=EUR&to=CNY&amount=100
```

that is *not* RESTful. You can say that this identifies a REST Resource.

But it *looks* like RPC (Remote Procedure Call) over HTTP which, in cases not as simple as currency conversion, will lead to a system that is not RESTful.

Always ask yourself: What are my Resources?

One answer could be: The Resource is the conversion *result*, identified by the two currencies and the amount. Then it would look more RESTful if you use

```
/conversion?from=EUR&to=CNY&amount=100
```

Note that the path is a noun (`conversion`), not a verb (`convert`). In general, if you can name a REST Resource with a noun, you are on the right track.

It is a matter of taste if you put the identifying bits into query parameters (`?from=EUR&to=CNY&amount=100`) or in the path. You could use

```
/conversion/EUR/100/CNY
```

using three path parameters:

```
/conversion/{FROM}/{AMOUNT}/{TO}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Convert

Your API looks fine to me:

```
/convert?from=EUR&to=CNY&amount=100
```

Lutz Horn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862064/4952669) also gives a good alternative.

## Calculate

If your API has to handle complex or lengthy operations, it might be a good idea to use POST:

```
/calculate
```

You can include the calculation in the request. This saves you from including long calculations in your URL.

If your API has to handle simple operations then you can use this design:

```
/calculate/add/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Similarly for `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide`, etc.

```
/calculate/subtract
/calculate/multiply
/calculate/divide
```

## Translate

For translation, I like Google Translate's API design:

```
/translate/{source}/{target}/value
```

Here, `source` is your source language (say EN) and `target` is your target language (say HI).

In the end, your API design comes down to your choice.

Comment: 'You can include the calculation in the request'. That would be RPC, not REST. What is the REST resource in this case?